# Jenkins: How to set environment variables for ant task by "source script"

Tags: java, shell, ant, jenkins, environment-variables

Imagine a classic `set_env.sh` shell script which **exports** some **environment variables**
which contents are calculated (non-static, depending on the file system).

In **Jenkins**, I'd like to execute this shell script  and afterwards calling an **ant** build step **using** the **previous environment from the script**.

Is there a way to do that in jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the [Envinject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin/) plugin. This lets you "inject" environment variables from a file so that they become part of the build environment, usable by all build steps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to *[source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Declarative)* the script, as in

```
. set_env.sh
```

That way, variables it exports are available in subsequent shell commands.

Comment: Yes, but when doing this they will still not be available in subsequent ANT build steps (which is the important part in the question)